# Как вызывать модальные окна с разным содержимым но с одним ID? BS 4

Tags: bootstrap

Добрый день. Такая ситуация, делаю дизайн на BS 4, сейчас работаю с FAQ в нем есть переменная, которая выводит вопросы и ответы, и обернута была в один DIV при нажатии на который, он раскрывался и было содержимое. Я обернула эту переменную в модальное окно BS 4, и столкнулась с проблемой, что все вопросы теперь обернуты в это модальное окно, но содержимое разное. Но при нажатии на кнопку, на любую из списка, выводится только содержимое первой кнопки. Есть такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.question').next().hide();
    $('.question').click(
        function()
        {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        }
    );
</script>
```

Но он почему-то не работает. У меня вообще возник вопрос, можно ли вызывать разное содержимое в модальных окнах, но при этом ID модального окна был один? Вот мое модальное окно:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">{$l.fQuestion}</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{$l.fQuestion}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       {$l.fAnswer}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Буду очень благодарна за подсказки.

Comment: Нет. ID должен быть уникальным в пределах страницы. Но вообще - я ничего не понял из этого описания и не представляю как оно должно работать

Comment: Думаю, что лучше прикрепить к вопросу скриншоты того как это выглядит в дизайне

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i4gf0w при нажатии на кнопку http://prntscr.com/i4gf5o

Comment: в Вашем html-е нет элементов с классом `question`

Comment: верно, они есть в старом варианте кода, извиняюсь

<div class="question" style="cursor: pointer;">
     <h2>{$l.fQuestion}</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: #F3F3F3; display: none;">
     {$l.fAnswer}
    </div>